# A list of funny / non competetive Poker Variants

Tags: home-game

I am about to host a small homegame. I am familiar with many variants of poker. From 8 Game over Short deck variants. 
Now for a birthday party and fun I am looking for "fun" variants.
Like: everybody holds on card up on his forehead so that all opponents can see the card. So the opponents can see that, but not the player himself.

Do you have any other fun games in mind? That would be awesome. I know this might not be a question which you can answer 100% but I would love to have 2-3 more variants just to increase the fun.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Like: everybody holds on card up on his forehead so that all
>   opponents can see the card. So the opponents can see that, but not the
>   player himself.

This is called Indian Poker and I am sure this is the only fun poker you'll ever need. Just wait until it gets to a showdown between a 2 and a 3

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pagat.com/poker/variants/

THIS WEBSITE - has a lot of games.

some of the explanations are easy to follow and some (like russian roulette) are so complex I probably couldn't figure them out if I tried.

I like the look of the game "FIVES" or f*cked up fives.

I get really bored when poker friends just want to play hold'em.

Indian poker is also a lot of fun - and good for learning to spot tells!

Have Fun!